# i want to use a for loop to find the frequency of numbers within a range in python. For example:

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv

i want to use a for loop to find the frequency of numbers within a range in python. For example:for the list below, i want to find the the frequency of numbers within 45-50, 55-60 and so on...

```
my_lst = [['52.2', '57.6', '54.3', '56.2', '48.4', '57.3', '50.8', '52.8', '60.9', '56.9'], 
 ['54.2', '57.8', '55.4', '56.3', '51.7', '61.2', '53.7', '54.6', '61.6', '60.4'], 
 ['56.2', '58.7', '61.1', '58.9', '54.8', '63.7', '58.3', '55.1', '65.8', '60.7'], 
 ['60.2', '61.3', '61.9', '61.6', '57.5', '66.7', '61.2', '57', '66.9', '62.4']]
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: solved it using the ff:                                                                    
                                                                                                    
  len([x for x in data.ravel() if 45 < x < 50]), to know the number of occurrences for a range of numbers in a csv file......